# Save CoreML model Prediction MLMultiArray to Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data, coreml

I want to save the `MLMultiArray` output generated from the CoreML model, to make it a persistent storage data.

```swift
let predictions = try model.prediction(from: input)
```

and the `predictions` is as below, as you can see, it's a `MultiArray(Float32)` type data.
[image]

However, in Core Data, it does not support this type. I noticed there was a type named `Transformable`, but I don't know whether it could works.

[image]

So I wonder if there is a feasible way to persist this kind of data ?

Comment: `MLMultiArray` conforms to `NSSecureCoding`, so you could use `NSKeyedArchiver` to encode it to `Data` then save that in Core Data, and use `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to decode it.

Comment: tranformable use for custom types for more https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/handling_different_data_types_in_core_data. You might simply convert into data before saving into core data

Comment: @SuryaKantSharma I tried add `@NSManaged public var feature: MLShapedArray<Float32>`, it shows the error `Property cannot be marked @NSManaged because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C`,  so I guess  `NSManaged` does not support `MLShapedArray<Float32>`

Comment: @ChipJarred  I've tried of using `NSKeyedArchiver` for encode/decode, it succeed when I encode & save `MLMultiArray`,  but faild when try to load with `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedArrayOfObjects`, the error was `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "value for key 'embedding' was of unexpected class 'MLMultiArray' (0x1e35d84b8) [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreML.framework].
Allowed classes are:
 {(
    "'MyApp.Embedding' (0x1002a53f8) [/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/C86A/MyApp.app]",
    "'NSArray' (0x1e3380b50) [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework] `

Comment: I'd need to see how you did the encoding, but I used `NSKeyedArchiver/Unarchiver` successfully in my answer below.  I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `MLMultiArray` conforms to `NSSecureCoding`  I was able to encode it to `Data` using `NSKeyedArchiver`, and decode using `NSKeyedUnarchiver`. The resulting `Data` instance could then be stored in Core Data or however else you might want to store it.

Since I don't have your model, I just created an instance of `MLMultiArray` explicitly, and set some values.

```swift
let predictions: MLMultiArray = try! .init(shape: [5, 5], dataType: .float32)

let p = predictions.dataPointer.bindMemory(to: Float32.self, capacity: 25)
for i in 0..<25 {
    p[i] = Float32(i)
}
```

I put the encoding/decoding code in functions, and made them generic, just in case you need it for other types:

```swift
import Foundation

func encode<T: NSSecureCoding>(_ value: T, secure: Bool = false) -> Data?
{
    let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver(requiringSecureCoding: secure)
    predictions.encode(with: archiver)
    archiver.finishEncoding()
    return archiver.encodedData
}

func decode<T: NSSecureCoding>(_ data: Data, as type: T.Type) -> T?
{
    guard let unarchiver = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingFrom: data) else {
        return nil
    }
    
    return T.init(coder: unarchiver)
}
```

then to use it:

```swift
guard let data = encode(predictions) else {
    fatalError("Encode failed")
}

// You can now save data to Core Data, or however else you want to persist it

guard let recoveredPredictions = decode(data, as: MLMultiArray.self) else {
    fatalError("Decode failed")
}
```

I also wrote some code to test that it works:

```swift
print(" original predictions: \(predictions)")
print("recovered predictions: \(recoveredPredictions)")

let r = recoveredPredictions.dataPointer
    .bindMemory(to: Float32.self, capacity: 25)
for i in 0..<25
{
    guard p[i] == r[i] else {
        fatalError("recoveredPredictions does not match predictions")
    }
}

print("Success")
```

The output is

```
 original predictions: Float32 5 × 5 matrix
[0,1,2,3,4;
 5,6,7,8,9;
 10,11,12,13,14;
 15,16,17,18,19;
 20,21,22,23,24]
recovered predictions: Float32 5 × 5 matrix
[0,1,2,3,4;
 5,6,7,8,9;
 10,11,12,13,14;
 15,16,17,18,19;
 20,21,22,23,24]
Success
```